# How to use WCF service to serialise data from SQL Server database and then send the XML to a FTP server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, wcf, ftp

I am kind of new to WCF. I am thinking about using a WCF service to serialize data from a SQL Server database, and the serialization has do be done against some custom schemas that I have.

Then after the data is converted into XML, I want to send that XML to a FTP server located another place. I don't know if this is possible?

If it is do any of you know a good way to do this?

I just have the standard `web.config` file that is created when you make a new solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="EuroPoultryConnectionString" 
             connectionString="Data Source=KEVIN\KEVINMSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=EuroPoultry;Integrated Security=True"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    </appSettings>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>    
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
                                   multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>

    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have been reading some stuff about WCF services, and I think I need to create a custom ABC somehow for this to be a success. Hope some of you can help with this or point me in a direction to a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need WCF to serialize objects - you can use `XmlSerializer`.  I'm curious as to what you mean by a "custom ABC".....

Comment: No i know that i dont need the wcf for serializing i just read that it is supposed to be faster than XmlSerializer. And i thought that it would be smart to use a wcf service since the data needed to be sent out to different platforms. What i mean about custom WCF is because i need to send to a FTP where i need to authorize who i am. Hope this is a good enough explanation.